# Access HttpServletRequest using @Context annotaion in business layer

Tags: java, spring, rest, jersey, jersey-2.0

I am able to access HttpServletRequest by using @Context annotation in my rest service. But unable to access the same in repository class.I do not want to pass the request form MyService to MyRespository while calling methods.

```
@Path("/someUrl")
public MyService{

@Context
private HttpServletRequest request;

@Get
public void someMethod()
{
   myRepository.someMethod();
}

}
```

But same annotation not working for my Repository class

```
@Repository
public MyRepository
{

@Context
private HttpServletRequest request;

public void someMethod()
{
 //need request here
}
}
```

it injection null request. Not sure why this is not working.

Comment: What Jersey version are you using?

Comment: @peeskillet - I am using jersey 2.11 version

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the way Jersey (and *its* DI framework HK2) is integrated, is that Spring components can be injected into Jersey (HK2) components, but not vice versa. `HttpServletRequest` is bound as a Jersey component.

What you can do is create an HK2 service, that wraps the Spring repo, and the `HttpServletRequest`. IMO, it is better design anyway. A repository shouldn't be concerned with the `HttpServletRequest`, it is only concerned with data.

So you can have

```
public class MyService {

    @Inject // or @Autowired (both work)
    private MyRepository repository;

    @Context
    private HttpServletRequest request;

}
```

Then bind the service with HK2

```
import org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.binding.AbstractBinder;
import org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScoped;

public class AppBinder extends AbstractBinder {

    @Override
    public void configure() {
        bindAsContract(MyService.class).in(RequestScoped.class);
        // note, if `MyService` is an interface, and you have 
        // an implementation, you should use the syntax
        //
        // bind(MyServiceImpl.class).to(MyService.class).in(...);
        //
        // Then you inject `MyService`. Whatever the `to(..)` is, 
        // that is what you can inject
    }
}
```

And register the binder with Jersey

```
public class JerseyConfig extends ResourceConfig {

    public JerseyConfig() {
        register(new AppBinder());
    }
}
```

Then you can inject `MyService` into your resource class.

If you don't want to go this route, then you need to make `MyRepository` an HK2 service, or use a an HK2 `Factory` to wrap the repository, and explicitly inject it. Something like

```
import javax.inject.Inject;
import org.glassfish.hk2.api.Factory;
import org.glassfish.hk2.api.ServiceLocator;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;

public class MyRepositoryFactory implements Factory<MyRepository> {

    private final MyRepository repo;

    @Inject
    public MyRepositoryFactory(ApplicationContext ctx, ServiceLocator locator) {
        MyRepository r = ctx.getBean(MyRepository.class);
        locator.inject(r);
        this.repo = r;
    }


    @Override
    public MyRepository provide() {
        return repo;
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose(MyRepository t) {/* noop */}
}
```

Then register the factory

```
@Override
public void configure() {
    bindFactory(MyRepositoryFactory.class).to(MyRepository.class).in(Singleton.class);
}
```

If you do the above, then you just use the `MyRepository`, instead of adding the service layer. Basically you need to get the repo from Spring, and explicitly inject it with the HK2 `ServiceLocator` (which is the HK2 analogue of the Spring `ApplicationContext`).